# How to insert object RealmList with copyToRealm

Tags: android, kotlin, realm

I try to insert realmList object to realm database

Model Data Class

```
open class Data : RealmObject() {

    @SerializedName("Settings")
    var settings: Settings? = null

    @SerializedName("Item")
    var items: RealmList<Items>? = null

}


fun insert(data: Data) {
        mRealm.executeTransactionAsync(
                Realm.Transaction { realm ->
                    val mData = realm.createObject(Data::class.java)
                    mData.settings = data.settings
                },
                Realm.Transaction.OnSuccess {
                    Log.e("setting", "success")
                }
        )
}
```

but it's error value is not a valid managed object. Then I found solution from this link https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/5238

```
fun insert(data: Data) {
        mRealm.executeTransactionAsync(
                Realm.Transaction { realm ->
                    val mData = realm.createObject(Data::class.java)
                    mData.settings = realm.copyToRealm(data.settings)
                },
                Realm.Transaction.OnSuccess {
                    Log.e("setting", "success")
                }
        )
}
```

When I try to insert RealmList in this solution is not work.
Please help thank a lot.

```
val mData = realm.createObject(Data::class.java)
mData.settings = realm.copyToRealm(data.settings) //setting is common object
mData.item = realm.copyToRealm(data.item)         //item is RealmList
```

Comment: Simply , write  "realm.copyToRealm(data)"

Comment: It work. Thank you guy.

Comment: Here I insert a list of objects in Realm:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65336647/10784151

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found solution. Thank mr.developer

```
realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(data)
```

Comment: Glad to help you :)